# wiring up the dropdownlist to run a function in a controller

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

so yeah... I have been searching for information about wiring up a dropdownlist so that it run a function in the controller with in the asp.net mvc tool.

```
$(function() {
    $("#title").change(function() {
        var selectedVal=$(this).val();
        $.getJSON("UserController/YourAction",{ id: selectedVal } , function(result) {
            //Now you can access the jSon data here in the result variable
        });
    });
});
```

Assuming you have an Action method called `YourAction` in your `UserController` which returns JSON

```
public ActionResult YourAction(int id)
{
    //TO DO : get data from wherever you want. 
    var result=new { Success="True", Message="Some Info"};
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

so when I use this it's not doing anything???
I don't know what json is but I know I don't need my application to return any thing...

So this what was tried... In the edit form I have this element:

```
$('#RES_TEST_ID').change(function () {
    var CurVID = $(this).val();
    var IntVID = $(document.getElementById('BUVID')).val();
    //alert(CurVID);
    //alert(IntVID);
    debugger 
    $.getJSON("TEST_REQUESTController/CheckCTEST", { Int_TEST_ID: IntTID, Cur_TEST_ID: CurTID }, function (result) {
    }); 
});
```

In the Edit controller... I tired this part in both the Post and Get sections as the post did not state where you should add this in your controller:

```
public ActionResult CheckChangeTEST(int Int_TEST_ID, int Cur_TEST_ID)
{
    if (Int_TEST_ID != Cur_TEST_ID)
    {
        var SelectedTEST = db.TEST_TEST_INFO.Find(Int_TEST_ID);
        SelectedTEST.VI_STATUS = 1;
        SelectedTEST = db.TEST_TEST_INFO.Find(Cur_TEST_ID);
        SelectedTEST.VI_STATUS = 2;
        var result = new { Success = "True", Message = "Some Info" };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return null;
}
```

For me, nothing happens... I try to see break points but they never go to the controller. Again I put this in both Post and get section under the edit control as I want this to run when the user edits changes the value in the dropdown list. Anyone have any Ideas they can share on what's going on here?

Comment: If your controller is `UserController` and your method is `YourAction()`, then the url needs to be `'/User/YourAction'`, )not `'UserController/YourAction'`) but always use `@Url.Action("YourAction", "User")'` to generate the correct url. And simply using your browser tools to debug your code would make it obvious you were getting a 404 error

Comment: hi stephen... i am not getting a 404 error is just will not goto debug when I am debugging the javascript debugs but not the code behind.... so I don't know of it's calling the function... I have no idea what i'm doing if I am honest... so it's all latin too me.. so you are saying use @  and not fwd slash, what does the @ do if I can ask? Many thanks for the help... I will give all these suggestions a try. Thanks!

Comment: If you open your browser developer tools (F12) and and look at console tab you would see the error

Comment: Also what are browser tools? Do I get this thru nugets?

Comment: Ahh ok thanks... should my call be in the get or post section of the controller if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @mcvdev The `@` symbol is Razor syntax. Razor is the default view engine that is used by ASP.NET MVC. Basically it allows you use things like the ViewBag, Models, etc. and allows you to write C# code inside your "html" files. If you notice the file extension on your views, it will be `.cshtml`, not plain `.html` because it is using the Razor view engine.

Comment: oh man I have some reading to do! Yeah I don't really understand razor... but with all of you guys help I am able to step into the function now! WOW I am blown away that this works!! Thanks to you all!!!

Comment: Your browser comes with a set of tools to assist in debugging. I strongly recommend you learn how to use them if you going to write scripts. If your using Chrome, start with [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: And if your method is altering data (for example changing something in a database), then always use a POST, otherwise it can be a GET or POST

Comment: Ahh ok... thanks again... yeah I think I am just doing this one project in mvc as it has been a real horror show... really tuff to grasp...I really am having a tuff time with it and the hard to understand concepts... I will be going back to webforms after this project is done. As I normally don't have to ask question on how to code stuff... this is a first for me and I am not a fan of asking for help. But thanks for the advice and showing me f12 but I am using IE and I am going to have to download chrome to see something useful I guess. Thanks a million gang!

Comment: All browsers have developer tools, and they all have help pages showing how to use them!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ajax call to your controller, you need to fix your route parameter for the Controller and for the action. The "Controller" name is automatically understood by the framework. So if you had FooController and you wanted to route to Bar action method, then you URL path would be `"Foo/Bar"`.

```
$.getJSON("TEST_REQUESTController/CheckCTEST" ...
```

should be

```
$.getJSON("TEST_REQUEST/CheckChangeTEST" ...
```

also on your action you can decorate the action with the Get attribute decorator:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CheckChangeTEST(int Int_TEST_ID, int Cur_TEST_ID)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Hi justsomedude... Ahh ok... the user above said I can use the @ as well... thanks for this... I will give both a try! I thank you for the help!! For some reason I can't give you a +1 on the answer... the system rejects my attempts.... but if I could I would so +1 Thanks!